# Why does LVM filesystem incorrectly show 100% usage?

Tags: lvm

On my Ubuntu 20.04 box, I have one 2TB disk that is running LVM filesystem.

```
sda                         8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   1.8T  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   1.8T  0 lvm  /
```

When I run df after a reboot, I see the following:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 1920250144 48480124 1791559780   3% /
```

However, once in a while, my system starts to misbehave. When I run df, I see that the lvm filesystem has taken 100% space.

I have no choice but to reboot the system. At this point, things are back to normal.

When I run "du" at the root level, the directory with maximum size is my home directory of about 25G. The next highest is snap at about 9G. Everything else is quite small when compared to 2TB disk.

I am wondering how I can diagnose the problem I have. This is the first time I ever used LVM filesystem and now I have doubts if it is buggy.

Comment: I use lvm since 2009 on and never have encountered anything like that. However, from your description it sounds like maybe something is filling your `/tmp` folder (this would mean that your use of lvm is irrelevant to the problem)